# Access ViewData & Session Variable in JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web project. We normally do not write HTML codes in aspx view page. All our HTML controls are dynamically created using Jquery. And we have referenced the JS file in the view page. So our view page does not even have any Jquery scripts. It only has references to number of JS files.

Now i have assigned a value in ViewData in my Controller. How can i access the value assigned in ViewData in my JS file? Remember this is a seperate JS file which is referenced in my View Page. And also we are not using Razor.

Please help me in this.

Comment: You can not use server-side code in any other separate js file. For this you have to use script tag in either your cshtml or aspx page.

Comment: in my opinion you will not be able get viewdata values in external js files...

Comment: So any workarounds or possible alternatives for achieving this? i simple wanted to transfer data from Controller to View and access tht through my seperate JS file.

Comment: you can do but using html data attributes